# "whatever" as an adverb in American English

Tags: american-english, dialect

Is "whatever" in the following sentences correct **in American English**? I only saw such use in British dictionaries.

> a. He will finish the project by himself **whatever**.

> b. He will back us **whatever**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current, colloquial, American English, 'whatever' is used as a "junk" word, indicating something about the speaker caring little about an issue. "You can do that or not do it, whatever" might be one such use.

The two sentences above would more commonly be used with some additional word: "He will finish the project whatever happens" or "He will back us whatever comes". So while the sentences are not incorrect, they do not use 'whatever' in a typical way.

Comment: Are you American?

Comment: Oh, yes. Thought people would assume that.